# Is OnActionExecuting thread-safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, thread-safety

I want to use userId field for checking user id in every action.
Is this approach thread-safe?

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); 
        path = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
    }
}
```

If it not correct can you suggest me other ways to do that.

Comment: A new controller instance is created for each request, so it should be fine. You can test this with: `public class AccountController: Controller { private Guid id; public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { id = Guid.NewGuid(); } [HttpGet] public IActionResult Test() { return Ok(id); }`